# What is wrong with the echo of this code

Tags: php

I tried alot but I kept getting error dont know why I tried using `/` but that didnot work too and keep giving me following error for following echo. Kindly let me know what I did wrong and how can I fix it?

Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

```
echo "<a href='stu.php?crs=$row['".'cid'."']'>My Chapter</a>";
```

Comment: Try echo "<a href='stu.php?crs=".$row['cid']."'>My Chapter</a>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an array value in a string like that.

You can either do this:

```
echo "<a href='stu.php?crs={$row['cid']}'>My Chapter</a>";
```

Or this:

```
echo "<a href='stu.php?crs=" . $row['cid'] . "'>My Chapter</a>";
```

Comment: @deceze which is bad practice, since it's unclear whether `cid` is a constant there.

Comment: No, within strings there are no constants. See [simple string interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).

Comment: @deceze Ok. But since `$row[cid]` on its own (outside of a string) is bad practice, I still wouldn't encourage it inside a string anyway.

Comment: Jus one last question in `{$row['cid']}` why did you use `{}`?

Comment: @user3027531 Look at that link that deceze provided: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple and scroll down to "Complex (curly) syntax"

Comment: @deceze On that link you provided, look at the example `"This is wrong: {$arr[foo][3]}"` "PHP first looks for a constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be thrown."

Comment: Yeah, `"{$arr[foo]}"` is wrong, `"$arr[foo]"` is not. Again, *simple syntax* vs. *curly syntax*. The simple syntax is its own special thing inside strings. The curly syntax is virtually the same as regular variables outside strings.

Comment: @deceze And yet... it's a constant within a string. =)

Comment: Meh, if that's what you're going on about... ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<a href='stu.php?crs=".$row['cid']."'>My Chapter</a>";
or
<a href='stu.php?crs=<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>'>My Chapter</a>
```